# How to model taxis in SUMO so that people only choose it if it is not too far away

Tags: simulation, sumo

This is my first try with taxis in SUMO, and I am defining an intermodal system with public transit and taxis for the moment.  Before adding the taxis, the agents either walk or took different public transit systems to go from start to finish by using modes="public" in the personTrips attributes.
I defined the vType taxicab like this:

```
<vType id="taxicab" vClass="taxi" personCapacity="4">
    <param key="has.taxi.device" value="true"/>
</vType>
```

and created 90 trips similar to this one:

```
<trip id="tax7478348" type="taxicab" depart="0.00"> 
    <stop lane="-174389084#0_0" triggered="person"/>
</trip>
<trip id="tax7242348" type="taxicab" depart="0.00"> 
    <stop lane="-201192895#0_0" triggered="person"/>
</trip>
```

My personTrips look like this:

```
<person id="7792" depart="3.42" departPos="random">
    <personTrip from="172099042#1" to="790209640#3" modes="public taxi"/>
</person>
```

The following situations happen when I run the simulation:

- The person agents move to the side of the road and wait for a taxi, all of them, regardless of how far away the taxis are.
- If a person agent started in a road that is not accessible by taxis, it just stays there, wait for the taxi and the program stops because the taxi cannot reach the person.

What do I want?

- People should determine if it is better for them to wait for the taxi, walk or use public transit based on different aspects (initially, simply time to arrive to destination)
  *When someone is in a place that is not taxi accessible, one of the following things should happen:

*The person should move to a road where taxis are allowed.
*The road should momentarily allow taxis (like if a person lives in a closed community, where only private vehicles are allowed, only taxis with people who live there would be allowed)
*The person should disregard that mode of transportation and choose another one.